# Flow shows error when array.map returns an incorrect type ignoring the 'filter'

Tags: javascript, flowtype

An example:

```
let foo: number[];

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .map(number => number === 1 ? number : null)
  .filter(number => number);
```

I get an error:

> 8:   .map(number => number === 1 ? number : null)
>                                               ^ Cannot assign `[...].map(...).filter(...)` to `foo` because null [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxgGM4DsDOALmFHHAFxi4CuAtgEYCmATgNoC6YAvGKwIwAaMAGYhNGDHYA6KAEsYhFgAoAHtwB8YFQEoA3OhiNipClTpM27fWDCoT3XoLAAmIcPaobU2gEMADko0DCwaZsHM3Fw8fGAA-GEWYJTiMNqeYDLyisyB5iFcmkEWeqhAA) is incompatible
>   with number [2] in array element.

(you can play with it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxgGM4DsDOALmFHHAFxi4CuAtgEYCmATgNoC6YAvGKwIwAaMAGYhNGDHYA6KAEsYhFgAoAHtwB8YFQEoA3OhiNipClTpM27fWDCoT3XoLAAmIcPaobU2gEMADko0DCwaZsHM3Fw8fGAA-GEWYJTiMNqeYDLyisyB5iFcmkEWeqhAA))

Flow look on the ".map" section and shows an error about the type since I return `null` sometimes and it expects numbers only.
However, it ignores the '.filter' I use, which eliminate all `null` values.

How I can work around it without using '$FlowFixMe' as I do want to get other Flow errors.

Comment: Well the `.filter()` happens *after* the `.map()` call. Maybe use `.reduce()` instead.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pointy, I can't use  `.reduce()` because I want to get an array as a result.

Comment: @David `.reduce()` returns what ever you want it to return

Comment: @Pointy, @Andreas, you guys are right. (I was just quickly replacing in my code the word `filter` to `reduce`, without thinking too much).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you **first** assign `null` values to an `integer array` using map and **then** you `filter` it. So in your first operation, `map`, will throw an error before `filter` gets called.

You can use `filter` directly in this case:

```
let foo: number[];

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .filter(number => number == 1);
```

---

When you want to `map` + `filter`, `reduce` can simplify your work:

```
let foo: number[];

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .reduce((acc, number) => number == 1 ? acc.concat(number + 1) : acc, [])
```

Comment: In the example above, I simplified the real use-case. 
Imagine that you do need the '.map' to return results with some calculation.
Here is an example:
`foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .map(number => number === 1 ? number + 1 : null)
  .filter(number => number);`

I know that called .map before the `.filter`, however, the `foo` gets the value as the end result of `.map` *and* `.filter`.

Comment: In fact, you are right, `foo` gets the value right after results of `map` and `filter`. My guess is `flow` doesn't support checker to chained functions. Anyway, you could make it using `reduce` as I made above.

Comment: thanks @guijob, that can work, and I won't get errors. The only thing is that, to me, it makes it less readable. Because my intent is not to reduce the original array. In the real case, I do lots of calculations in the `.map` section and I rarely return `null`. I wish I could somehow teach Flow to take the 'filter' into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

From the other comments, I see that this is a simplification of your actual use case.  The `map` is redundant in your example and misleading, you could achieve the same simply with `filter`, but lets assume you do in fact need that step.

It seems that you want `foo` to be an array of numbers OR null to support the `map` operation, and then you want to filter out the nulls.

You are using the short form of the array syntax (`number[]`) which you can't use if you want to type the array elements as optional.  This will allow you to specify that `null` is a permitted value.

```
let foo: Array<?number>;

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .map(number => number === 1 ? number : null)
  .filter(number => number);
```

Note that this is also permitting `undefined`, so you may in fact prefer:

```
let foo: Array<number | null>;

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .map(number => number === 1 ? number : null)
  .filter(number => number);
```

Your filter is coercing `number` to a truthy value, which will filter out valid numbers equal to zero (your example may be over simplified in this respect).

```
let foo: Array<number | null>;

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .map(number => number === 1 ? number : null)
  .filter(number => typeof number === 'number');
```

You might want to consider `Array.reduce` as an alternative that would allow you to apply both the map and filter operations in one pass.

```
let foo: Array<number | null>;

foo = [1, 2, 3]
  .reduce((memo, number) => {
    if (number === 1) {
      return [ ...memo, number ];
    }
    return memo;
  }, []);
```

If you don't want to use Array spread (`...`) then you can use either `memo.push(number)` or `memo.concat([number])` depending on your preference for mutability of `memo`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that flow does not support this case. Instead of switching to `.reduce()`, I opted for switching to `.forEach()` which I think is more readable than the `reduce` alternative.

```js
const foo: number[];

[1, 2, 3].forEach(number => {
   if (number === 1) {
      foo.push(number);
   }
})
```